# Generating Random Linear Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, grassmannian, haar-measure

Let $n$ and $m$ be two integers such that $m\leq n$. Let $G_{n,m}$ be the set of **all** m-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume we want to generate a subspace of dimension $m$ which is distributed uniformly over $G_{n,m}$.

**Claim**:

Let $A$ be $n \times m$ random matrix such that each entry distributed as $N(0,1)$ (normal distribution). Let $E = \text{span}(c_1,\dots,c_m)$ where $c_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be the $i$-th column of $A$. Then, $E$ is distributed uniformly over $G_{n,m}$.

[I am looking for an elementary proof of this claim. This claim is stated in Chapter 5 of Vershynin's HDP book without proof.]

Comment: What is the definition of "distributed uniformly over $G_{n,m}$"?

Comment: @EricWofsey I do not know the exact definition. I quoted the exact statement from Chapter 5 of Vershynin's HDP book.

Comment: Well you cannot prove anything without a definition.  It seems plausible to me that this statement is intended to *be* the definition of the uniform distribution on $G_{n,m}$.

Comment: See Stiefeld manifold and uniform measure on Wikipedia. Your problem can be solved by observing that N(0,In) is invariant by the orthogonal group. Perfect explanations and examples can be found in the book by Leopoldo Nachbin 'The Haar Measure' 196? –